# SmartfoxServer implementation with Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, smartfoxserver

Hell,
I want to create a cloud server using Amazon EC2 and SmartFox. I succesfully installed SmartFox on windows machine Amazon provided me, configuered it so i have the private ip as they told me in the documentation, if i try to connect as private-ip:8080 it works(from the same machine) but with the public ip it doesn't. I don't know why.  Thank you .

Comment: And if i try the public dns:8080 on the remote machine works but on base machine it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i managed to get this through. Now first Change the security groups settings to accept 8080 inside the Management Console, and then go to windows firewall inside the machine and chenage in Adcanced settings in inbounds rules and add a new rule.